# function prints strange characters : v����

Tags: c

**MAIN.C** triggers function **b()**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include "main.h"

int main() {


const char *a;
a = b();

printf("%s\n", a);


}
```

function **b()** in **MAIN.H** responds with result

```
static inline const char *b(){

const char* retu;
char query[300];

sprintf(query, "select * from TEST limit 1");

retu = query;

    return retu;
}
```

this is what **MAIN.C** script prints:

```
v����
```

it is strange stuff. not as expected. ( intended )

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined. You're lucky that it *didn't* work, see the duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

`retu` is pointing to `query`, which goes out of scope when b is finished, so the memory is no longer valid in main.

To make a string that outlasts b, you need to allocate it on the heap, e.g. using malloc.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* retu;
char query[300];
sprintf(query, "select * from TEST limit 1");
retu = query;
return retu;
}  //query goes out of scope here
```

As soon as the function ends `query` goes out of scope since it is declared on stack.Now you are trying to refer this memory after it has gone out of scope which is undefined behavior.You can allocate `query` on heap.Also remember to free the memory.

```
 char *query = malloc(sizeof(char) * 300);
```